# How do I install "provider.aws" for terraform on a Mac?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Corporate firewall seems to block this repo, so I tried to add a provider manually into the .terraform.d/plugins directly.  `terraform init` works But for `terraform plan` I get this error message:

> - provider.aws: fork/exec /Users/headley/.terraform.d/plugins/terraform-provider-aws_v1.28.0_x4: exec format error

I downloaded the provider file directly from:

https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform-provider-aws/1.28.0/

...selecting "linux_amd_64" for my MacBookPro.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  The os on mac is Darwin, which is not linux.  Use this plugin:

terraform-provider-aws_v1.28.0_x4